# Pass JSON result to second webservice to get final results using Alamofire Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I have two web services and using Alamofire.

- First web Services is `.get` method and I already get the JSON result.
- For Second web services is `.post`method I need to pass first web service JSON result to parameter for final data list.

Want to Achieve: Pass first web service json data to second web service (parameter) or any suggestion to get final data.
Please any one help ....

First Web Service:

```
Alamofire.request("http://GetConstantTableList", method: .get, encoding: encoding, headers: [ "Accept":"application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer \(token ?? "")"])
.responseJSON { respo in
print(respo)
```

Result First Web Service:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "actionType": 101,
            "version": 1
        },
        {
            "actionType": 1015,
            "version": 1
        }

        ]
}
```

Second Web Service:

```
Alamofire.request("http://GetConstantTableData", method: .post, parameters: ???  encoding: encoding, headers: [ "Accept":"application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer \(token ?? "")"])
.responseJSON { response in
print(response)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the data as it is you are getting from the first api?

Comment: @Aakash Yes as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the pass the response of first api directly by calling the second api inside the response block of the first api.

```
private func callFirstApi() {
    Alamofire.request("http://GetConstantTableList", method: .get, encoding: encoding, headers: [ "Accept":"application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer \(token ?? "")"])
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                if let parameters = value as? [String: Any] {
                    callSecondApi(with: parameters)
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
    }
}

private func callSecondApi(with parameters: [String: Any]) {
    Alamofire.request("http://GetConstantTableData", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: [ "Accept":"application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer \(token ?? "")"])
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have applied your code and `if let parameters = response as? [String: Any] ` giving error `Error: `
`Cast from 'DataResponse<Any>' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails `